# force figures to follow each other

Tags: floats

Consider this example that involves two figures forming a continued float:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\lipsum[4][1-2]
\begin{figure}[h!p]
  \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight, width =0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Examples}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!p]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textheight]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

It is not a good idea to have text inserted among a continued float after all. How to expel anything that gets between two figures?

Comment: You are looking for `subfigure`?

Comment: @JouleV No. I am dealing with a continuous float that spans several pages.

Comment: Your're probably looking for the `placeins` package and its `\FloatBarrier`

Comment: Or use `[b!p]` for the first float.

Comment: `[!hp]` prevents top or bottom floats and allows h even if that is taking up too much of the page so makes the floats being separated far more likely than the default positioning.

Comment: perhaps you want `[p]` on both the figures.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `b!` doesn't work in all cases - I had a table inserted instead of text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `p` for the subsequent floats also doesn't work. The only solution I have found as stable is using `\newpage`.

Comment: using `\newpage` with floats is a strange choice, better to use `\clearpage` But it seems that you do not want anything to float at all, why are you using `figure` and not simply `\includegraphics` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle to have caption and cross-references

Comment: you don't need a float for that: you could use the (one line) `capt-of` package, or use `[H]` to stop floating or several other options.